# Android Compose Crash

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I have a crash on Firebase Crashalytics that I dont understand. Can somebody help me make sense of it? The report does not point to any line number in the codebase so cannot really post code. Here is the crash report..`Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1, size 4 at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:183) at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:166) at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutIntervalContent.getKey(LazyLayoutIntervalContent.kt:86) at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider.getKey(LazyLayoutPager.kt:197) at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasureKt.getAndMeasure-SGf7dI0(PagerMeasure.kt:462) at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasureKt.measurePager-ntgEbfI(PagerMeasure.kt:184) at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasurePolicyKt$rememberPagerMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(PagerMeasurePolicy.kt:159) at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerMeasurePolicyKt$rememberPagerMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(PagerMeasurePolicy.kt:66) at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:107) at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:100) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:704) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:583) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:582) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:291) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:567) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:566) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:291) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:646) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:114) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingNode.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:397) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-_EkL_-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:112) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:71) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingNode.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:397) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:1008) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:136) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:1008) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-_EkL_-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:112) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:71) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:1008) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-_EkL_-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:112) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:71) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollingLayoutNode.measure-3p2s80s(Scroll.kt:391) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:583) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:582) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:291) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:567) at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:566) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:291) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:646) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-_EkL_-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:112) at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:71) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:562) at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:38) at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1555) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473) at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133) at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1551) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:583) at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1147) at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:329) at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureOnly(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:537) at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.recurseRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:401) at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureOnly(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:379) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:996) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:302) at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:289) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:372) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278) at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594) at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552) at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7403) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1390) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27853) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:4882) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:3461) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3767) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3151) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:11068) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1321) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1329) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:930) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:859) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1303) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8810) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)`

I cannot try anything until I know whta the problem is, no idea where I should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack Compose is not good for debugging. However, you can diagnosis with Preview or get a hint from the log.

It says, `Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1, size 4 at ...`

So, this is list size problem. And also you can find `Lazy` thing in the stacktrace. That means it could get that crash from LazyColumn or LazyRow Whatever.

Make sure that you don't have where you access some list with the index -1.